# How can I fully extend the official WebRTC DataChannel example for remote peers?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, webrtc

I've been doing a lot of research into WebRTC for the past few days- I've read http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/, and have implemented the http://simpl.info/rtcdatachannel/ example on a local server. 
I can attempt to follow the code in the example, but I'm confused about how actual remote peers communicate. I added an ICE server to the example:

```
window.localPeerConnection = new webkitRTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [{ url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }] },
{optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]});
```

...

```
window.remotePeerConnection = new webkitRTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [{ url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }] },
{optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]});
```

But there's still no syncing between browsers when I send data, or any indication that data communication is occurring. I understand that there's something I'm missing- is it setting up a signalling server?

Can someone help me by extending the example so that it actually sends data back and forth between connected peers?

Comment: May these docs/tutorials (https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/#documentations) help you. Or one-page demos: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/demos#chrome-to-chrome-webrtc-data-connection

Comment: Yeah, that one page demo is a perfect example of what I'm talking about- the browser is talking to a itself, not to an external peer! I understand that I have to implement signaling through like socket.io, but I'm confused about why every example seems to gloss over this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link here - https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab/src/6daf0496dc78?at=master

You're interested in Step 5 and Step 6 - but to be fair, if you don't have much experience with this, I'd go through all the steps - it did help me a lot.

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

A simple if slightly ugly "calls itself and transfers files" test is [here](http://mozilla.github.com/webrtc_landing/data_test.html).  I few notes (at least on Mozilla): call CreateDataChannel() before createOffer().  You can add more channels any time later, but you must (for now) call it once at the start from the caller (offerer).  Note that Chrome 30 is just transitioning to spec-compliant DataChannels from a very different, non-standard implementation with a bunch of limits that aren't in the spec.

Comment: SCTP-based (spec-compliant) DataChannel support should land in Chrome 31